# Parse CSV to Array using JAVAScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

I have generated a CSV from Excel Sheet with following attributes.

1.img # 2.fabric 3.Description  4.web item 5.copy 6.price 7.STYLE #   8.DEPT 9.NUMBER 10.SIZES  11. COLOR1 12.COLOR2  13.COLOR3  14.LINK

Some rows have null attributes. 
For example a line in CSV which has data for all attributes.

20,ORGANIC COTTON BABY RIB,100% ORGANIC COTTON,Y,Scoop Neck Long Slim Tank,,F2ORB-U0839,"P, W",Arnica,Pewter,Primrose,/EileenFisher/collection/ShopByCategory/Tanks_and_Camis/PRD_SBORB-U0839M/Scoop+Neck+Long+Slim+Tank+in+Organic+Cotton+Baby+Rib.jsp?bmLocale=en_US

But I have data(rows or lines) in CSV where some attributes don't have any value for example.

img url,WASHABLE STRETCH CREPE,"70% VISCOSE, 24% NYLON, 6% LYCRA",,Wide-Leg Cropped Pants with Yoke,,F2TK-P0123,,Black,,,

I want to parese such to a 2D in javascript to use in my website. Please help me with explanation.

Comment: Dear I am new to JScript but I am a java programmer. I am concerned about the null values?

Comment: I don't know if you're concerned or not. PS: java programmers that don't know how to use google, that's interesting o_O